# Using Regex to match numbers on rows of different size in Python

Tags: python, regex, matching

I have a file that contain positive and negative numbers in row of different sizes. I am trying to extract the numbers using regex.However, it is skips some rows as below.

Part of the Input file:

```
.
.
.
...s --   -0.28096  -0.27907  -0.27770  -0.27730  -0.27573
...s --   -0.27149  -0.27076  -0.27036  -0.26883  -0.26794
...s --   -0.26301  -0.26114  -0.26098  -0.25950  -0.25891
...s --   -0.25536  -0.25209  -0.24952  -0.24903  -0.24533
...s --   **-0.24351  -0.23272  -0.07408**
...s --   -0.01149  -0.01028  -0.00892  -0.00888  -0.00665
...s --   -0.00445  -0.00268  -0.00006   **0.00109   0.00187**
...s --    **0.00295   0.00318   0.00470   0.00575   0.00696**
.
.
.
```

My code:

```
with open('Input') as x:
    file.write('Output')
    file.write("\n")
    for t in itertools.islice(x,7821,7831):
        k = re.search(r'(?<=s\s\S\S\s\s\s)[+-]?\d+\.\d+|\d+\s\s\[-+]?\d+\.\d+|\d+\s\s\[-+]?\d+\.\d+|\d+\s\s\[-+]?\d+\.\d+|\d+\s\s\[-+]?\d+\.\d+|\d+' , t)

        if k:
            r1.append(k.group())
    file.write(str(' '.join(map(str,r1))))
```

The output

Output

```
-0.28096  -0.27907  -0.27770  -0.27730  -0.27573 -0.27149  -0.27076  -0.27036  -0.26883  -0.26794 -0.26301  -0.26114  -0.26098  -0.25950  -0.25891 -0.25536  -0.25209  -0.24952  -0.24903  -0.24533 -0.01149  -0.01028  -0.00892  -0.00888  -0.00665
```

As you can see the output does not contain the numbers in ***bold*** in the input file.

How should I modified the code to make it more inclusive and extract all the data between the lines I put in the range? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex only allows negative numbers, and it also requires at least 5 numbers in a line.

Try `(?<=s\s\S\S\s)(\s\s[- ]\d+\.\d+)+`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solves it! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Another quick question. How could I know the line number where the phrase first occurs in a text file. I used the following but it prints all lines that has the phrase.                                                                                    with open('Input') as x:
    for num, line in enumerate(x, 1):
        if word in line:
            print num

Comment: @T.A. Set `first_occurrence= None` and inside the loop do `if first_occurrence is None: first_occurrence= num`.

Comment: Another question that I just posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980459/choosing-only-non-zeros-from-a-long-list-of-numbers-in-text-file?noredirect=1#comment65313637_38980459

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex.

```
import io                                                 

text = '''                                                
...s --   -0.28096  -0.27907  -0.27770  -0.27730  -0.27573
...s --   -0.27149  -0.27076  -0.27036  -0.26883  -0.26794
...s --   -0.26114  -0.26098  0.25950  -0.25891           
...s --   -0.25536  -0.25209  -0.24952  -0.24903  -0.24533
'''.strip()      

# replace this with whatever index makes sense for you.        
start_of_nums = 7                                 

with io.StringIO(text) as f:                              
    for line in f:                                        
        print(line[start_of_nums:].strip().split())
```

Comment: Thank you wayne! Quick question. How could I know the line number where the phrase first occurs in a text file. I used the following but it prints all lines that has the phrase. with open('Input') as x: for num, line in enumerate(x, 1): if word in line: print num

Comment: Hopefully there's some kind of sentinel - either where `--` is the Nth and Nth+1 character, or some other pattern that you can look for. Or it's always N number of lines down. If not, your best approach would probably be trying to convert the last N groups per line to float and continuing to the next line if  the conversion fails. `TypeError`, I think.

Comment: Another quick question for yo, Wayne:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980459/choosing-only-non-zeros-from-a-long-list-of-numbers-in-text-file?noredirect=1#comment65313637_38980459