# Choosing only non-zeros from a long list of numbers in text file

Tags: python, list, numbers

I have a  text file with a long list of numbers. I would like to choose only the non-zeros and make another text file.

This is a portion of the input file:

```
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  5.16677E-30
9.61708E-28  1.18779E-25  9.73432E-24  5.29352E-22  1.91009E-20  4.57336E-19
7.26588E-18  7.65971E-17  5.35806E-16  2.48699E-15  7.65973E-15  1.56539E-14
2.12278E-14  1.91010E-14  1.14046E-14  4.51832E-15  1.18780E-15  2.07196E-16
2.39824E-17  1.84193E-18  9.38698E-20  3.17431E-21  7.12271E-23  1.06050E-24
1.04773E-26  6.86848E-29  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
```

The expected out put for the portion of the input show above would be:

```
5.16677E-30 9.61708E-28  1.18779E-25  9.73432E-24  5.29352E-22  1.91009E-20                                                                    
4.57336E-19 7.26588E-18  7.65971E-17  5.35806E-16  2.48699E-15  7.65973E-15    
1.56539E-14 2.12278E-14  1.91010E-14  1.14046E-14  4.51832E-15  1.18780E-15  
2.07196E-16 2.39824E-17  1.84193E-18  9.38698E-20  3.17431E-21  7.12271E-23    
1.06050E-24 1.04773E-26
```

I tried what I wrote below but it is not returning anything.

```
r1=[]
file = open ('aa2','w')
with open('aa.txt') as m:
    file.write('List')
    file.write("\n")
    for t in itertools.islice(m,500,6500):
        for i in t:
            if i != 0.00000E+00 :
                d = i

         k = re.search(r'([- ]\d+\.\d+)+' , d)

         if k:
            r1.append(k.group())
    file.write(str(' '.join(map(str,r1)))) 
file.close()
```

Comment: Show example text from the input file so we know what format it is in. Then show the expected output.

Comment: @T.A. you can [edit] your question to include the sample input and output. Also note that your code indention is screwed up. Please fix that, too.

Comment: Edit the question. Don't post it as comments. Format it in a way people can easily see. It isn't clear from comments if the numbers are separated by one or more spaces, newlines, tabs, etc. Otherwise most folks will just skip over this question. We have to understand what you have and what you want in order to help you. [Read this explanation of How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I apologize for the first post. I made the recommended changes

Answer (score 0):

You're using regex again where you don't need to. You're also doing something exceedingly bizarre where you're using `islice` on the file. That's also unnecessary. You could just do this:

```
import io                                                                     

file = io.StringIO('''                                                        
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  5.16677E-30  
9.61708E-28  1.18779E-25  9.73432E-24  5.29352E-22  1.91009E-20  4.57336E-19  
7.26588E-18  7.65971E-17  5.35806E-16  2.48699E-15  7.65973E-15  1.56539E-14  
2.12278E-14  1.91010E-14  1.14046E-14  4.51832E-15  1.18780E-15  2.07196E-16  
2.39824E-17  1.84193E-18  9.38698E-20  3.17431E-21  7.12271E-23  1.06050E-24  
1.04773E-26  6.86848E-29  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00                            
'''.strip())                                                                  

#################################
# Actual Answer to your problem #                                                                            
#################################  
values = []                                                                   
for line in file:                                                             
    values.extend(val for val in line.strip().split() if val != '0.00000E+00')

with io.StringIO() as out:           
    for i, val in enumerate(values): 
        if i and not i % 6:          
            out.write('\n')          
        out.write(val+' ')           
     out.seek(0)
     print(out.read())
```